# XSLT format gYearMonth and gYear

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

I have a XML document with XSD schema and XSLT transformation to XHTML. In the schema I'm using the `xs:gYearMonth` and `xs:gYear` types because in those nodes I don't require the whole date. I know that there is an XSLT function `format-date` that can print `xs:date` in specified formats.

[Here](https://www.oxygenxml.com/archives/xsl-list/200408/msg00297.html) is a proposed solution, to create a function that takes `gYear` or `gYearMonth` and create a date from it and then call `format-date` on it. Problem is that there isn't written how to actually code it.

This is what I've put together so far. Note that I don't need to pass other arguments than the actual date since the formatting will be same for all occurrences.

```
<xsl:function name="format-gYearMonth">
    <xsl:param name="date" as="xs:gYearMonth"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="format-date(xs:date(concat($date, '-00')), '[MNn], [Y]', 'en')"/>
</xsl:function>
```

Also I can't seem to find XSLT 2.0 validator that would tell me what exactly is wrong in this code. `xsltproc` can only validate XSLT 1.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to provide a namespace to your function name, as in

```
  <xsl:function name="mf:format-yearMonth" as="xs:string">
      <xsl:param name="yearMonth" as="xs:gYearMonth"/>
      <xsl:sequence select="format-date(xs:date($yearMonth || '-01'), '[MNn], [Y]')"/>
  </xsl:function>
```

Complete sample is https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPqsHSU

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
    xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
    xmlns:array="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/array"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs math map array mf"
    expand-text="yes"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:function name="mf:format-yearMonth" as="xs:string">
      <xsl:param name="yearMonth" as="xs:gYearMonth"/>
      <xsl:sequence select="format-date(xs:date($yearMonth || '-01'), '[MNn], [Y]')"/>
  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="yearMonth">
      <xsl:copy>{mf:format-yearMonth(.)}</xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and outputs `April, 2004` for input `2004-04`.

For XSLT 2 you would use `<xsl:value-of select="mf:format-yearMonth(.)"/>` instead of `{mf:format-yearMonth(.)}`.

If you want to provide a language argument to format-date you need to provide it as the third argument but also need to specify the fourth and fifth argument (at least as empty sequences): `format-date(xs:date($yearMonth || '-01'), '[MNn], [Y]', 'es', (), ())`. However, you need Saxon PE or EE and additionally the ICU library to support various languages.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I can't get it to work in browser. When I open it in the online app you provided it works with saxon engine and other end with error that my custom naspace's link doesn't contain anything. What should this link contain and is it even required?

Comment: Browsers only support XSLT 1.0 so don't expect such a feature (neither `xsl:function` nor XSD data types nor `format-date`) to be supported by the browser's XSLT engine.

Comment: Oh well and is there any other way I can format date in browser?

Comment: With XSLT 1 you need to check first whether there is EXSLT support for e.g. http://exslt.org/date/functions/format-date/index.html respectively whether you can use the function based or template based implementations provided there, otherwise you will have to roll your own template.

Comment: Ok I think I need to find some other way to do this then. Maybe with javascript? Anyway, this answer solves my question even thou the answered question doesn't solve my issue :D